# The function wp_update_post() returns 0 for certain posts

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the `wp_update_post()` function to update certain posts. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/

The function updates a lot of posts but sometimes, it fails. I did a `var_dump()` to see what it returns on failure and got `int(0)`.

I read the documentation of the function and it contains the following code:

```
// First, get all of the original fields.
$post = get_post( $update_post['ID'], ARRAY_A );

if ( is_null( $post ) ) {
    if ( $wp_error ) {
        return new WP_Error( 'invalid_post', __( 'Invalid post ID.' ) );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So, it returns 0 if the `$post` is null. However, I could see that the variable `$post` is populated with all the correct data when I run a `var_dump()`.

Here is my code for `$update_post` array.

```
$update_post = array(
    'ID' => $post_id,
    'post_title' => $post_title,
    'post_content' => $post_content,
    'post_excerpt' => $post_excerpt,
    'tags_input' => $post_tags,
    'post_status'   => 'publish'
);
```

The post ID has a valid value of `2084` (There is a published post with this ID). All other fields are populated as well. How can I get this function to work?

I would like to once again mention that I can still update many other posts. The problem only occurs with post-ID 2084 (as far as I know).

Based on the suggestino by @CBroe, I changed my function to `wp_update_post($update_post, true)`.

This gave me the following output:

```
object(WP_Error)#1639 (2) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { ["db_update_error"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(37) "Could not update post in the database" } } ["error_data"]=> array(0) { } }
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_post/:

> $wp_error
>   (bool) (Optional) Allow return of WP_Error on failure.
>   Default value: false

You need to pass `true` as second parameter to `wp_update_post`, for it to return an instance of `WP_Error` on failure.

If you don’t do that … then it will just return `0` instead, if something went wrong.

So add that parameter, and *then* var_dump the result of that call, so that the `WP_Error` object can tell you what actually went wrong.

Comment: Thanks @CBroe. I have updated the question to include the error I received. :)

Comment: That is a pretty generic error. Some quick research suggests that a common cause could be problems with character encoding. You should check what your data array for updating this particular post actually contains.

Comment: This is the way of figuring out why it is failing, thank you @CBroe